# Subquery returning multiple values ... not permitted to do so

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @week1S DATE = '07/01/2016';
declare @week1E DATE = '07/07/2016';

WITH A as (
SELECT COUNT(ARB_accomplished) as ARB_accomplished_CNT 
FROM arbimport
WHERE Requested_date between @week1S and @week1E AND arb_accomplished LIKE 'Y'
GROUP BY dispatch_group_name
)
Update ArbitrageResponse
Set arb_count1 = (SELECT ARB_accomplished_CNT FROM A)
```

I'm trying to update the column in one table based on a count of responses in another table. I'm trying to group on dispgroups and since my import table is massive I'm trying to filter it down to a selected date range. I'm going to have to run this a lot so It would be cool to keep the variables but not neccessary.

I want my response table to be recording responses every week so I just need columns being added to this table which is why I did an update.

I am getting an error

"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

I'm not sure if this has to do with my variables as they are being called in my subquery - I know that my subquery is returning the aggregated results of many different rows. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help convey what you are trying to do.  The error message is quite clear; what you want to do is not.

Comment: your query `SELECT ARB_accomplished_CNT FROM A` returning multiple values since you grouping by dispatch_group_name. you might want to use join in your update statement if you are updating arb_count1 based on dispatch_group_name

Comment: as niketshah90 says, you probably want your update statement to look something like this: `UPDATE AR SET arb_count1 = A.ARB_accomplished_CNT FROM ArbitrageResponse AR JOIN A ON A.dispatch_group_name = AR.dispatch_group_name` and modify your CTE to include the dispatch_group_name...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
set  @countaccomplished = SELECT COUNT(ARB_accomplished) as ARB_accomplished_CNT 
FROM arbimport
WHERE Requested_date between @week1S and @week1E AND arb_accomplished LIKE 'Y'
GROUP BY dispatch_group_name WHERE DISPATCH_GROUP_NAME = SOMETHING

Update ArbitrageResponse
Set arb_count1 = @countaccomplished
```

OR

```
WITH A as (
SELECT COUNT(ARB_accomplished) as ARB_accomplished_CNT, dispatch_group_name 
FROM arbimport
WHERE Requested_date between @week1S and @week1E AND arb_accomplished LIKE 'Y'
GROUP BY dispatch_group_name
)
Update b 
Set b.arb_count1 = a.ARB_accomplished_CNT  
FROM ArbitrageResponse b where a.dispatch_group_name= b.dispatch_group_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the structure of your table, this is just a guess:

```
WITH A as (
      SELECT dispatch_group_name, COUNT(ARB_accomplished) as ARB_accomplished_CNT 
      FROM arbimport
      WHERE Requested_date between @week1S and @week1E AND arb_accomplished LIKE 'Y'
      GROUP BY dispatch_group_name
     )
UPDATE ar
    SET arb_count1 = a.ARB_accomplished_CNT
    FROM ArbitrageResponse ar JOIN
         A
         ON ar.dispatch_group_name = a.dispatch_group_name
```